# list based menu is flowing the the next line when zoomed in or out

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Hi 
I am trying to make a site with list based menu. It look the way I want but as soon as I zoom in or out the menu flows to the newt row. It's happening in every browser (but at different zoom levels.)

I have found few similar topics on this forum and tried using those solution. But nothing seem to be working.

You could have a look at the website yourself at www.empoise.com (the upper menu). 
If you need any other info please let me know.

I have been trying to resolve it for last many months!

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you

T

Comment: Good question, I've always wondered why zooming affects width. No idea why.

Comment: You could try using relative dimensions, both for font and their container (em and %)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this:

```
.span-13 {width:200px;}
.span-11 {width:730px;float:right;}
#header #menu {float:right;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Comment: Thank you Aaviya. But I am using Blueprint for the layout which already has different values for those classes.
If you could explain how the above code could resolve the issue. I could try to use some use some other class for the same.

Comment: Still can't fix it. Anyone? :(